# Flume Agent failure Handlling

Tags: hadoop, flume

I have written flume agent which will be running 24/7 on production server. But some time I have observed that flume agent silently goes down.

I need a mechanism which can atleast give an alert to client/user when such kind of scenario happens.

Any suggestion to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

First off: I recon it's best for you to check out the logs to see why Flume crashes. If nothing is there, see if you can change the logging level to `WARN` or `INFO`, because Flume isn't supposed to crash. It's been running for ages on my boxes.

In case you want to proceed creating that monitoring mechanism: afaik Flume doesn't support such a thing, but a simple bash script should do the trick. Here is an example. You'll have to customize the command that takes action when Flume is down.

```
#!/bin/bash
process_identification_str='flume-ng'
while "true"; do
    ps=$(ps aux | grep "$process_identification_str" | grep -v 'grep')
    if [ -z "$ps" ]; then
        echo 'ALARM!'
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was wondering if we can use any tool that comes along with HDP. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

See what I found: "Monitoring in Flume is still a work in progress. Changes can happen very often. Several Flume components report metrics to the JMX platform MBean server. These metrics can be queried using Jconsole."

https://books.google.com.co/books?id=u1bTBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=Monitoring+in+Flume+is+still+a+work+in+progress.+Changes+can+happen+very+often.+Several+Flume+components+report+metrics+to+the+JMX+platform+MBean+server.+These+metrics+can+be+queried+using+Jconsole.&source=bl&ots=WgCjzsZ399&sig=CUra1DUhWgx0H87HZ59FdwdW-9E&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD3dvVoJrRAhXMSSYKHWHqDzsQ6AEIGzAA

It seems it is not possible to natively monitor this component for now.

Regards!